# ¿Es posible seleccionar el script de esta forma MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo que eliminar el código por el que empiezan estas sentencias de SQL ya que son innecesarias y dificultan la ejecución del script, son mas de 400, hay alguna forma de eliminarlas todas de una sola vez o seleccionar el texto hacia abajo?. Les dejo parte del codigo por si les sirve.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
< ='17:07:09'>INSERT INTO articulos (codigo,nombre,descripcion,precio,cantidad)&#x0A;values (1,'blusa','Banana Republic',680.50,350)</>
SELECT * FROM articulos</>
INSERT INTO articulos values (2,'tenis','nike',999.63,125)</>
< ='17:10:51'>INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (3,'lentes','prada',890.99,15)</>
< ='17:11:29'>INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (4,'sandalias','puma',745.89,78)</>
< ='17:11:35'>SELECT * FROM articulos</>
< ='17:15:35'>SHOW databases</>
< ='17:15:45'>DROP TABLE articulos</>
< ='17:16:02'>SELECT * FROM articulos</>
< ='17:16:07'>CREATE TABLE articulos( &#x0A;codigo INT,&#x0A;nombre VARCHAR(20),&#x0A;descripcion VARCHAR(30),&#x0A;precio DECIMAL(5,2),  -- se le pueden agregar parentesis el primer numero es la longitud &#x0A;cantidad INT       -- de los numeros y el segundo es la longitud de decimales&#x0A;)</>
< ='17:16:12'>INSERT INTO articulos (codigo,nombre,descripcion,precio,cantidad)&#x0A;values (1,'blusa','Banana Republic',680.50,350)</>
< ='17:16:15'>SELECT * FROM articulos</>
< ='17:16:24'>INSERT INTO articulos values (2,'tenis','nike',999.63,125)</>
< ='17:16:27'>INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (3,'lentes','prada',890.99,15)</>
< ='17:16:29'>INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (4,'sandalias','puma',745.89,78)</>
< ='17:16:32'>SELECT * FROM articulos</>
< ='17:19:09'>SELECT * FROM articulos where codigo = 3</>
< ='17:20:32'>SELECT * FROM articulos where nombre = 'LENTES'</>
< ='17:21:54'>SELECT * FROM articulos where descripcion = 'puma'</>
< ='17:23:38'>SELECT cantidad,precio FROM articulos where descripcion = 'nike'</>
< ='17:23:49'
< ='17:23:56'>SELECT cantidad, precio FROM articulos where descripcion = 'puma'</>
< ='17:27:15'>SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE nombre &lt;&gt; 'blusa'</>
< ='17:28:50'>SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE precio &gt; 800</>
< ='17:29:15'>SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE precio &lt; 800</>
< ='17:29:58'>SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE cantidad &gt;= 300</>
< ='17:31:43'>SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE cantidad &gt; 78</>
< ='17:31:47'>SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE cantidad &gt;= 78</>
< ='14:11:24'>DELETE FROM articulos WHERE codigo = 1</>
< ='14:11:47'
< ='14:12:13'>SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE nombre &lt;&gt; 'blusa'</>
< ='14:12:16'>DELETE FROM articulos WHERE codigo = 1</>
< ='14:13:24'>DESCRIBE articulos</>
< ='14:13:28'>DELETE FROM articulos WHERE codigo = 1</>
< ='14:14:32'>SELECT * FROM articulos</>
< ='14:15:16'>DELETE FROM articulos WHERE nombre = 'lentes'</>
< ='14:15:20'>SELECT * FROM articulos</>
< ='14:16:19'>DELETE FROM articulos WHERE precio = 999.63</>
< ='14:16:25'>SELECT * FROM articulos</>
< ='14:17:56'>DELETE FROM articulos</>
```

Comment: Con una herramienta que tenga soporte para expresiones regulares, puedes extraer el texto que te interesa. Incluso hay algunas en línea, como https://regexr.com/

Comment: No creo que en mysql workbench puedas hacerlo, pero desde luego cualquier lenguaje de programación te permite aplicar un regex para eliminar esas partes. Por ejemplo en JS es realmente sencillo, [aquí](https://paiza.io/projects/wrM7a7UUfBw6aWPqF9B6WQ) te dejo un pequeño script que hace exactamente eso.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes valerte de una expresión regular para extraer los datos del formato en el que los tienes.

He construido una expresión regular que hace lo que entiendo que quieres y la he puesto en esta misma respuesta, de manera que si ejecutas el snippet copias y pegas el texto original y le das procesar, te va a devolver el script que buscas.

A manera de ejemplo el formulario se carga con un par de líneas que copie de tu pregunta.

```js
function procesar() {
  let inTexto = document.getElementById("texto");
  let outSQL = document.getElementById("sql");
  let txt = inTexto.value;
  let exp = /^(< ='\d+:\d+:\d+'>)(.*)(<\/>)$/gm;
  let sql = '';
  txt.split(/[\r\n]+/).forEach(function(e) {
    //console.log(e);
    if (e.match(exp)) sql += e.replace(exp, '$2') + '\n';
  });
  outSQL.value = sql;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%; height=200px">
  <label for="texto">Script SQL original</sql>
  <textarea id="texto" style="width:100%; height:100px">
&lt; ='17:07:09'&gt;INSERT INTO articulos (codigo,nombre,descripcion,precio,cantidad)&amp;#x0A;values (1,'blusa','Banana Republic',680.50,350)&lt;/&gt;
&lt; ='17:10:51'&gt;INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (3,'lentes','prada',890.99,15)&lt;/&gt;
&lt; ='14:17:56'&gt;DELETE FROM articulos&lt;/&gt;
</textarea>
  <button id="procesar" onclick="procesar()">Procesar</button><br/>
  <label for="sql">Script SQL limpio</sql>
  <textarea id="sql" style="width:100%; height:100px"></textarea>
</div>
```

OJO, que sobre el resultado aún habrá otras sustituciones que hacer si buscas ejecutar el script, ya que incluye cosas *extrañas* como `&#x0A;` (que supongo que es un <kbd>enter</kbd>, que te tocará detectar, sustituir y/o eliminar a manera de limpiar el script para su ejecución.